# Set value of GPIO247 to 1

Tags: linux, embedded, yocto, gpio, bsp

I am currently trying to enable GPIO Port 247 it is located in GPIOCHIP7.
The output of cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio is

```
gpiochip7: GPIOs 224-255, parent: platform/48053000.gpio, gpio:
 gpio-226 (                    |reset               ) out hi
 gpio-227 (                    |sysfs               ) out hi
 gpio-228 (                    |pcie-reset          ) out hi
 gpio-229 (                    |sysfs               ) out lo
 gpio-230 (                    |id                  ) in  lo IRQ
 gpio-231 (                    |pcie-clk-oe         ) out hi
 gpio-247 (                    |enable              ) out lo
```

I need to set gpio-247 to hi.

My Linux kernel version is 4.9 and i am on a AM57x

I have tried these but to no avail

```
echo 247 > /sys/class/gpio/export returns "echo: write error: Device or resource busy".
echo 247 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport returns "echo: write error: Invalid argument".
```

i can echo everything except 247.

Comment: Hi bibira6546, you you please augment your original question with the output of the following command: `gpioinfo gpiochip7` ? thanks.

Comment: Modify your device tree accordingly. Currently that line (according to your debug output) is busy. It means some code in the Linux kernel is in charge of changing states of that pin.